# SQlite3 commands aren't displaying tables from rails tutorial application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

This is probably something simple I'm missing. I'm working through the pragmatic bookshelf ruby on rails exercises in the AWDWR 4th edition.

Everything was going well and then I ran into the portion where you enter into the sqlite 3 command line tools to make sure it's capturing the order information.

When I try to run the select statement for orders, I get:

```
sqlite> select * from orders;
SQL error: no such table: orders
```

Then I tried listing all the tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>
```

I get to the sqlite command line per the instructions in the book:

```
sqlite3 -line
```

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify  a database filename on your *sqlite3* command line. Usually<sup>*</sup>, if you do not give a database filename, then it will start out operating on an empty, temporary, in-memory database.

<sup>*
The version I have at hand (*sqlite3* 3.7.2) actually takes `-line` as the database filename if there are no additional arguments. This means that I end up with a file named `-line`; this file can be deleted with `rm ./-line`.</sup>

You probably want this (run from the root directory of your application):

```
sqlite3 -line db/development.sqlite3
```

---

If your project is using Rails 3, then you can use this:

```
rails db
```

If you need the `-line` behavior, you can use `.mode line` at the *sqlite3* command line.

If you want to access the DB for a non-default environment, just append the environment name:

```
rails db staging
```

You can also add in `-p` if you want to automatically use the username and password from your configuration (*sqlite3* does not need a username or password since it uses plain Unix permissions):

```
rails db -p production
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I appreciate it. I'll give this a shot as soon as I can get to my development machine.

Comment: I looked at the file system and saw the database name was: development.sqlite3 So I ran: sqlite3 -line db/development.sqlite3 and I was able to see the tables and run queries against them. I wonder if I made a misstep somewhere in the tutorial that took me off this path. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Taking another look at the book tonight, I realized that the orientation of the book on my iPad made the command line unclear to me. The right path is there and if I turned the iPad around so I could see the entire page, it was absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1):

To display all the tables in the sqlite:

```
>select * from sqlite_master
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I run that sql statement, I still get nothing back: sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
sqlite>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (not getting anything back), but I'm using Windows, and it seems to have a problem when I use the drives with the path (c:\ or d:). I was able to solve it by and launching sqllite from the db path, and using only the file name, like this:

```
C:\mydir\sqlite3.exe  -line mydb.db
.tables
```

or

```
C:\mydir\sqlite3.exe
.open mydb.db
```

or

```
C:\mydir\sqlite3.exe
ATTACH "mydb.db" AS db1;
```

To display a table:

```
select * from mytable;
```

or

```
select * from db1.mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into the db folder by terminal and type

```
$ sqlite3 development.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .table
```

and it will show the tables you have made.